# Express home route not being detected

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, routes

So what happens is app.use('*') or even app.get doesn't catch the home route and won't redirect to https until you go to any other route.

Any clues as to what is causing this?

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

//Hiding cert information

const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

app.enable('trust proxy')

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.secure ? next() : res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url)
})

//Moved it to be underneath the http middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './website/build'), { dotfiles: 'allow' }));


app.use((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './website/build/index.html'));
});
```

Going to the website does nothing, but the second I go to any non-home route it works.

Edit:

So turns out the issue was with app.use(express.static()) taking priority over the https redirect middleware. Changing it like this solved the problem

Comment: can you show the router for the other paths? also is your "app" express? why create server with http?

Comment: I think we'd have to see ALL the code in the exact order things are declared.  If `app` is registered with both servers and your first `app.use()` statement shown is the first one, it should get first crack at every incoming request.  But, if you have something else like an `express.static()` route FIRST, then all bets are off.  We need to see ALL the code.

Comment: Edited to add full code, it might be the express static I'll try messing with that no idea how that could be the cause though.

Answer (score 0):

app.use(express.static()) was taking priority over the other app.use()

Modified code so that the redirect takes priority

Credits to @jfriend00 for finding the answer